# MySQL on delete cascade doesn't work...I'm using mac os x lion and sequel pro

Tags: mysql, macos, cascade, cascading-deletes

I cannot make it work. An example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                     ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Does your CREATE fail, or does your DELETE on a parent row fail to delete the children rows referencing it?

Comment: delete fails, I want child to delete when parent does it

Comment: Add in the question, the code you are running.

Comment: I can create tables, but when I delete a parent, his children doesn't delete

Answer (score 1):

When creating the child table your reference has to be a constraint

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

If that fails, use the following query to check if your configuration checks for references

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'
```